# Changing background color via rgb sliders?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 3 sliders created. I need to be able to change the background color of a canvas based on the sliders value. Can someone please assist me? I have look long and hard for a method but nothing seems to work. Here is my slider code,

Backend code:

```
     /// <summary>
    /// On the click event of the GetColor() button we het the color code
    /// which sets with the help of slider control and display it in message box.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush colorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)stackPanel1.Background;
        MessageBox.Show(colorBrush.Color.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to create color by taking values from
    /// slider one, two, three and then change the background color
    /// of stack panel.
    /// </summary>

    public void changeColor()
    {
        byte rr = (byte)slider1.Value; //Retriving values from slider1
        byte gg = (byte)slider2.Value; //Retriving values from slider2
        byte bb = (byte)slider3.Value; //Retriving values from slider3
        Color cc = Color.FromRgb(rr, gg, bb); //Create object of Color class.
        SolidColorBrush colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(cc); //Creating object of SolidColorBruch class.
        stackPanel1.Background = colorBrush; //Setting background of stack panel.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is called when the window is first time loaded in memory
    /// And change the background of panel control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        changeColor();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is called whenever the value of slider1 control is changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColor();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is called whenever the value of slider2 control is changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>

    private void slider2_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColor();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This event is called whenever value of the slider3 control is changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>

    private void slider3_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        changeColor();
    }
```

Slider code in xaml

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Height="135" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,24,0,0" x:Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" />
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,184,0,0" x:Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" Maximum="255" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Value="0" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" />
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,229,0,0" x:Name="slider2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Maximum="255" Minimum="0" SmallChange="1" ValueChanged="slider2_ValueChanged" Background="Lime" />
    <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,267,0,0" x:Name="slider3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" SmallChange="1" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Maximum="255" ValueChanged="slider3_ValueChanged" Background="Blue" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,184,0,0" x:Name="textBlock1" Text="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,229,0,0" x:Name="textBlock2" Text="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,267,0,0" x:Name="textBlock3" Text="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34" />
    <Button Content="Get Color" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="378,288,0,0" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" Click="button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Your question lacks specifics and is unclear. Please fix it by including a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and stating _specifically_ what that problem is. Explain in precise terms what the code you have now does, and what you want it to do instead. Telling us _"nothing seems to work"_ is uninformative.

Comment: What are you doing with the slider values? Anything? What happens in `RedSlider_ValueChanged` etc.? Anything?

Comment: I am sorry. I sent the wrong code updated post. Here is my problem. I have the sliders made but in the xaml.cs  I am just unaware of how to bind them. Like how would I set a property to bind to a brush that I can use dynamically instead of the stackpanel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To Bind the `TextBlocks` with Value of Slider, I used Behaviours.

Below is one sample from `slider1`

```
<Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Maximum="255" SmallChange="1" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged" TickPlacement="TopLeft" Value="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
            <i:EventTrigger.Actions>
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlock1}" PropertyName="Text" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger.Actions>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

You already have a Method GetColor() which updates `StackPanel` Background. So I used the same. and changed the Slider's `ValueChanged` to single Event (`Slider_ValueChanged`)

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    GetColour();
}

public void GetColour()
{
    byte rr = (byte)slider1.Value;
    byte gg = (byte)slider2.Value;
    byte bb = (byte)slider3.Value;
    Color cc = Color.FromRgb(rr, gg, bb);
    SolidColorBrush colorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(cc);
    stackPanel1.Background = colorBrush;
    MyColour.Text = colorBrush.Color.ToString();
}
```

End Output.

[image]

Full Project can be found [here](https://github.com/avknaidu/SOIssue43766411)

Comment: Thank you and just to be sure what do I enter on the  background option if I want to use it for a different resource

Comment: i did that for you already. Look at `MyColour` TextBlock. You can use the same as background for other resources. Similar to how you are doing it to `stackpanel`.

Comment: Awesome missed that bit sorry.  Thank you again

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, Mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works, however I am running into a problem. I keep getting The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. How can I bypass this and allow changes in real time?

Comment: @KrystalIsabelShaw Thats a whole different question/Issue altogether. It would be helpful if you post a new question and show how you are assigning/Using Color for other resources.

Comment: Ok @AVK. I got the permissions issue fixed. However the resource keeps setting itself back to black. Using the code you sent me.  Any ideas?